# Forcing Webalizer to include images in URL list

Tags: webalizer

I would like to know how many hits are received by images hosted on a virtual host. I use webalizer as my statistics program. I've hit a wall.

In order to achieve this, I edited webalizer.conf and commented out the following lines:

```
# Usually you want to hide these
# HideURL *.gif
# HideURL *.GIF
# HideURL *.jpg
# HideURL *.JPG
# HideURL *.png
# HideURL *.PNG
# HideURL *.ra
```

Then, I ran webalizer from the command line. I know that it ran because numbers were updated on the statistics pages. However, image URLs are still not included. I'm quite at a loss as to where I'm going wrong.

Update:
I have tried these further things. I've added the following to webalizer.conf:

```
PageType     png
PageType     jpg
PageType     gif
```

This is not the behavior that I want, but I'm getting desperate here.
I have added:

```
IncludeURL    *.png
IncludeURL    *.gif
IncludeURL    *.jpg
```

Still no-go. Getting very frustrated here.

Comment: FAQ question 10 maybe? http://www.webalizer.org/faq.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel kind of stupid: the problem was that Webalizer was running on the new logs being created AFTER I made the change, not the old statistics that had already been processed. Which is the correct behavior. After I gave it some time, the images started showing up in the stats.